# Text Box associated on click of RadioButton

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, radio-button

Plzz someone tell me what's the problem in my code below ...as the **first function(changeME**) is working BUT THE **2ND function (inputName**) is not working....is there some problem with the variables?? As m New in asp.net plzz help me out with some basic concept which I might be missing.

```
 `PROJECT
  <input type="radio" name="portal" id="radio1" onclick="changeMe(this);"/> &nbsp; <input type="text" name="textprojectOff" id="text1" value="Project Name" onclick="changeMe(this);"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 


<script type="text/javascript" >
    function changeMe(inField) {
        var fieldId = inField.id;
        var type = fieldId.substring(0, 4);

        if (type == 'text') {
            var name = fieldId.substring(4);
            var radioButton = document.getElementById("radio" + name);
            radioButton.checked = true;
        } else {
            var name = fieldId.substring(5);
            var textField = document.getElementById("text" + name);
            textField.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
NON-PROJECT<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="portal" onclick="inputName(this)"/> &nbsp; <input type="text" name="textnonprojectOff" id="text2" value="Departement" onclick="inputName(this);"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function inputName(inDepartment){
       var departmentId=inDepartment.id;
       var type= departmentId.substring(0,4);

  if (type== 'text'){
      var name= inDepartment.substring(4);
      var radioButton=document.getElementById("radio"+ name);
      radioButton.checked=true;
  }
   else{
       var name=inDepartment.substring(5);
       var textfield=document.getElementById("text"+name);
       textfield.focus();
      }

</script>
```

`protected void RadioButton2_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            {
                TextBox11.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox11.Visible = false;
                TextBox11.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        protected void RadioButton3_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadioButton3.Checked)
            {
                TextBox12.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox12.Visible = false;
                TextBox12.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }`
Anyone can plzzz modify this code according to my previous requirement as my AIM  is Same as previous but now I m using codebehind for it...but its not working properly..
plz chk out the fiddle given in the previous answers and kindly modify this code accordingly.

Comment: so you want the radiobutton to be selected when you type something specific into the textbox..?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net

Comment: you haven't closed `function inputName(inDepartment){` `**}**` paranthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/hg66d/1/)**

```
function inputName(inDepartment){
       var departmentId=inDepartment.id;
       var type= departmentId.substring(0,4);

  if (type== 'text'){
      var name= departmentId.substring(4);
      var radioButton=document.getElementById("radio"+ name);
      radioButton.checked=true;
  }
  else{
       var name=departmentId.substring(5);
       var textfield=document.getElementById("text"+name);
       textfield.focus();
      }
  }
```

`var name= departmentId.substring(4);` and not `var name= inDepartment.substring(4);`

- **inDepartment** is an object you are passing as a parameter . **substring()** method wont work on it.
- Plus, you could've reused the same function for both the elements; no need to write separate functions.

Comment: thank u so much ...u solved my problem...nd I know that was a quite a blunder I was doing..u saved my half day!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Do comment on this post in case of any issue in the code.

Comment: @Ben- NO .. I just want the text box associated with each of the radio button get active only when that particular radiobutton is clicked...well my problem is solved thanks to Shaunakde...but thanks for ur intrest in my question

Comment: thnkeww so much...as m Really new in asp.net and c# especially..so m very often get these stupid problems..so GOD knows my next prblm can encounter me in any time........

Comment: how to make the Text visible in the textbox INVISIBLE as soon as the related radio button is clicked?? for elaboration -if I click on radio button 'project' the text box beside it showing "project name" get blank for user to input there data....help plZZ!!

Comment: `textField.value = ' ';` add this line after `textField.focus();`

Comment: how to write this javascript coding of onclick function into C# code in aspx.cs file???`                                           <script type="text/javascript">
    function myconfirm() {

        var txt;
        var x = confirm("confirmation!!");
        if (x == true) {

            txt = " Your Request is Submitted!";
        }
        else {
            txt = "Verify and Confirm!";
        }
        document.getElementById("verify").innerHTML = txt;

        return false;
    }
</script>`

Comment: thnkeww for the previous answer @shaunakde

Comment: Glad to Help :) . I guess you can't. You can but its complex. Instead write it in .aspx. http://forums.asp.net/t/1303143.aspx?How+to+write+javascript+code+in+aspx+cs+file+

Comment: m trying something like this    `public void myconfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
        string x= "confirmation!!";string txt;
            if (x=="true")
            {
               txt= "your request is submitted!";
            }
            else {
                txt="verify and confirm!";
            }`

Comment: You can return this response using JSON object from your controller.

Comment: ohkk ..no pblm ..thnks for ur efforts @ shanakde